# Shade Every Other Row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, xlsxwriter

I want to shade every other column excluding the 1st row/header with grey. I read through the documentation for XLSX Writer and was unable to find any example for this, I also searched through the tag here and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to post the details on how I did this, and how I was able to do it dynamically. It's kinda hacky, but I'm new to Python and I just needed this to work for right now.

```
xlsW = pd.ExcelWriter(finalReportFileName)
rptMatchingDoe.to_excel(xlsW,'Room Counts Not Matching',index=False)
workbook = xlsW.book
rptMatchingSheet = xlsW.sheets['Room Counts Not Matching']
formatShadeRows = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#a9c9ff',
                                       'font_color': 'black'})
rptMatchingSheet.conditional_format('A1:'+xlsAlpha[rptMatchingDoeColCount]+matchingCount,{'type': 'formula', 
                                                                                          'criteria': '=MOD(ROW(),2) = 0', 
                                                                                          'format': formatShadeRows})
xlsW.save()
```

xlsAlpha is a list that contains the max amount of columns my report could possible have. My first three columns are always consistent so I just set rptMatchingDoeColCount equal to 2 and then when I loop through the list to build my query I increment the count. The matchingCount variable is just a fetchone() result from a count(*) query on the view I'm pulling from in the database.

Eventually I think I will write a function to replace the hardcoded list assigned to xlsAlpha, so that it can be a virtually unlimited amount of columns.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I could improve this feel free to share.

Answer (score 2):

why not set it up as a conditional format?

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_conditional_format.html

you should just declare a  condition like "if cells row number %2 == 0"

Comment: I saw that page, and I thought the answer to my question would be there, but I was unable to find and example of shading every other row. Also I forgot to mention that I'm not sure how to go about setting the range either since the document I'm working with varies everytime I generate it.

Comment: looks to me that the criteria needs to be something like: `=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A1<>"")` ?

Comment: @Acid Burn 85 For a conditional formatting implementation of alternative rows see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576498/applying-formatting-row-by-row-in-addition-to-column-formatting-with-xlsxwriter/30792513?noredirect=1#comment49915953_30792513).

Comment: @jmcnamara Thanks! That worked! Is there a way to dynamically assign the range of cells to ones with data?

Comment: @Acid Burn 85 Dynamically, no. Just track the range that you are writing data to and use that as the range to `conditional_format()`.