# How to adjust the Excel row height in pandas.ExcelWriter()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I have several pandas data frame and I'm using ExcelWriter to create an Excel sheet. My all data frame go to one Excel sheet ("Sheet1") and at the end, I'm writing a long sentence.("CompanyName:ABC \n Country:USA").
I usually use the below command.

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data 1': [11, 12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data 2': [21, 22, 23]})
#df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data 3': [31, 32, 33, 34]})
d = {'id1': ['85643', '85644','85643','8564312','8564314','85645','8564316','85646','8564318','85647','85648','85649','85655','56731','34566','78931','78931'],'ID': ['G-00001', 'G-00001','G-00002','G-00002','G-00002','G-00001','G-00001','G-00001','G-00001','G-00001','G-00002','G-00002','G-00002','G-00002','G-00003','G-00003','G-00003'],'col1': [671, 2,5,3,4,5,60,0,0,6,3,2,4,32,3,1,23],'Goal': [np.nan, 56,78,np.nan,89,73,np.nan ,np.nan ,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 34,np.nan, 7, 84,np.nan,5 ], 'col2': [793, 4,8,32,43,55,610,0,0,16,23,72,48,3,28,5,3],'col3': [500, 22,89,33,44,55,60,1,5,6,3,2,4,13,12,14,98],'Date': ['2021-06-13', '2021-06-13','2021-06-14','2021-06-13','2021-06-14','2021-06-15','2021-06-15','2021-06-13','2021-06-16','2021-06-13','2021-06-13','2021-06-13','2021-06-16','2021-05-23','2021-05-13','2021-03-26','2021-05-13']}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_example.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

start_row = 0

# Output the data frames and keep track of the start/end row.
for df in (df1, df2, df3):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False)
    start_row += df.shape[0] + 1

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_zoom(60)
worksheet.set_default_row(41)

# Add a format
header2 = workbook.add_format({
    'bold':     True,
    'align':    'center',
    'border':   6,
    'valign':   'vcenter',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'font_name': 'Calibri',
    'font_size': 12,
    'text_wrap': True
})

# Write a merge range.
start_col = 0
end_col = 3

worksheet.merge_range(start_row, start_col, start_row + 1, end_col,
                      "CompanyName: ABC\nCountry: USA", header2)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

In here I set up the same row height for every row. using

```py
worksheet.set_default_row(41)
```

But I want to set data frames header for 50-row height and
values for 35-row height. Also, I want to add a blank row in-between data frames.

is it possible to do this in pandas.ExcelWriter or any other way in python?
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can find the answer here:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576498/applying-formatting-row-by-row-in-addition-to-column-formatting-with-xlsxwriter)

Comment: @amirali This is for row by row formatting write? I mean like it's kinda formatted odd and even rows. But I want to format data frame headers and values with different row heights. My data frame length is changing each time too. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can change the if clause to:
`for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    if row== 1:
        worksheet9.write_row(row + 2, 1, row_data, format1)
    else:
        worksheet9.write_row(row + 2, 1, row_data, format2)
`
where format1 will be the header format, format 2 will be the rest.

Comment: Didn't work it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to set the row height with XlsxWriter is with [set_row()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-row). The `set_default_row()` method isn't the correct method to use here.

Here is modified version of your example to use `set_row()` to set the header and data row heights. I also adjusted it to insert a blank line between the data frames.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data 1': [11, 12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data 2': [21, 22, 23]})

d = {'id1': ['85643', '85644', '85643', '8564312', '8564314', '85645', '8564316', '85646', '8564318', '85647', '85648', '85649', '85655', '56731', '34566', '78931', '78931'], 'ID': ['G-00001',  'G-00001', 'G-00002', 'G-00002', 'G-00002', 'G-00001', 'G-00001', 'G-00001', 'G-00001', 'G-00001', 'G-00002', 'G-00002', 'G-00002', 'G-00002', 'G-00003', 'G-00003', 'G-00003'], 'col1': [671,  2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 60, 0, 0, 6, 3, 2, 4, 32, 3, 1, 23], 'Goal': [np.nan,  56, 78, np.nan, 89, 73, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  34, np.nan,  7,  84, np.nan, 5],  'col2': [793,  4, 8, 32, 43, 55, 610, 0, 0, 16, 23, 72, 48, 3, 28, 5, 3], 'col3': [500,  22, 89, 33, 44, 55, 60, 1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 13, 12, 14, 98], 'Date': ['2021-06-13',  '2021-06-13', '2021-06-14', '2021-06-13', '2021-06-14', '2021-06-15', '2021-06-15', '2021-06-13', '2021-06-16', '2021-06-13', '2021-06-13', '2021-06-13', '2021-06-16', '2021-05-23', '2021-05-13', '2021-03-26', '2021-05-13']}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_example.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

start_row = 0

# Output the data frames and keep track of the start/end row.
for df in (df1, df2, df3):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False)
    start_row += df.shape[0] + 2

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_zoom(60)

# Add a format
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold':     True,
    'align':    'center',
    'border':   6,
    'valign':   'vcenter',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'font_name': 'Calibri',
    'font_size': 12,
    'text_wrap': True
})

# Write a merge range.
start_row -= 1
start_col = 0
end_col = 3

worksheet.merge_range(start_row, start_col, start_row + 1, end_col,
                      "CompanyName: ABC\nCountry: USA", merge_format)

# Adjust header and data row heights.
start_row = 0
for df in (df1, df2, df3):
    worksheet.set_row(start_row, 50)

    for row_num in range(start_row + 1, start_row + df.shape[0] + 1):
        worksheet.set_row(row_num, 35)

    start_row += df.shape[0] + 2

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]